# weex js installation fails

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, weex

I am trying to install weex on ubuntu linux and when I run the usual command for that:

> sudo npm install -g weex-toolkit

it returns the error seen in the picture below. It's complaining that I am not using Mac. But weex should be able to run on both platforms. When I then try to run:

> weex

it says command not found (ie it's not installed). Any help greatly appreciated.

[image: weex installation error]

Answer (score 0):

Try by this registry.

> npm install -g weex-toolkit --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org

or add `sudo` as needed.